# Out-of-Memory on Tomcat

Tags: jvm, tomcat7, jvm-arguments, jvm-crash

I am using Tomcat 7 to deploy my application (using spring controllers) and i see the following exception happening at times on my server. Please help. Do understand that this has something to do with my server memory, but what could be the fact that i have wrong..I am also giving my ulimit details at the end. This happens only at times and not always. No specific repeating scenario or interval of occurrence...

I am using a Red Hat 6 (64 bit) OS
The JVM specifics that is set are :  -Xms1024m -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

```
27 Dec 2013 10:56:15,462 DEBUG [http-bio-5004-exec-41] DispatcherServlet:910 - Could  not complete request
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.doFilter(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:171)
    at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.invokeFilterChain(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor$FilterChainServletWrapper.service(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:359)
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor.onRequest(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:204)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:237)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:163)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:101)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.doService(Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.java:67)
    at org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketUtil.doService(TomcatWebSocketUtil.java:95)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.service(Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.java:62)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1675)
.......

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:691)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache$1.run(KeepAliveCache.java:112)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache$1.run(KeepAliveCache.java:96)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache.put(KeepAliveCache.java:95)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.putInKeepAliveCache(HttpClient.java:353)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.finished(HttpClient.java:341)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream.close(KeepAliveStream.java:100)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.justRead(MeteredStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:135)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3052)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3046)
    at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:112)
    at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(FileCopyUtils.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getResponseBody(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:385)
    at com.payoda.appviewx.web.adapter.rest.AdapterBase.sendRequest(AdapterBase.java:90)
    at com.payoda.appviewx.web.adapter.rest.DiscoverDeviceAdapter.discoverDeviceByRange(DiscoverDeviceAdapter.java:63)
    at com.payoda.appviewx.web.controller.DeviceController.getDiscoverDeviceUsingRange(DeviceController.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    ... 71 more
```

The details of ulimit are given below

```
Ulimit details
----------------
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127515
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 20000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 65536
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: The JVM Heap is getting exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Create file "setenv.sh" ("setenv.bat") in your $CATALINA_HOME/bin, put the following content into it:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
```

then restart tomcat.

If it does not solve the problem, try changing parameters "Xms" and "Xmx" to higher values.

**Important:** don't forget to set executable bit to "setenv.sh" (if you are on Linux).

Comment: I am using a Red Hat 6 (64 bit) OS The JVM specifics that is set are : -Xms1024m -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m. May be i try to increase Xms to 1024 and Xmx to 1240.. Should this be a good number?

Comment: My humble advice: try maximum value at first. "Maximum" should be defined as follows: if you increase it even more, tomcat would not start at all. If maximum value solves the issue, then decrease the value until the error is reproducible again.

Comment: Please let me know what maximum you are mentioning about. Did u mean start with xms and xms as 1240 and then try to decrease the value of xms step by step..

Comment: Example: if my computer has 8 GB operating memory installed, I'd try  -Xmx7000m (assuming that 1 GB is used by OS and some other apps). If tomcat does not start with 7000, then decrease it to 6000 etc.

Comment: Ok got it.. but i have a problem with that . First is that i cannot scale beyond 1.2GB as i have other applications running on the same box (ActiveMQ, Karaf, MongoDB etc) etc depending on this 8GB ram. Second my xmx and xms as 1024 starts my tomcat properly and even works fine. Only at times (may be after 4-5 days or sometimes never) i run into this issue of outofmemory..

Comment: That means either Tomcat or your servlets are allocating more and more memory. Your JVM limits should cover your worst case, not your initial case. Or see if you can get your application to reduce its allocations; and make sure everything you discard is gc-able.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with ulimit; JVM imposes its own maximum memory limit. When launching java from command line, you'd use `-Xmx10g` for 10Gb max memory for JVM, for example. For Tomcat, the place to put the settings depends on which OS you have and how you installed Tomcat.

For example, on Debian with the Tomcat from debian package, you'd typically edit `/etc/default/tomcat...` and put `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx10g"` in it (or however much you want).

Comment: I am using a Red Hat 6 (64 bit) OS The JVM specifics that is set are : -Xms1024m -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m